# How to read the "groupid" from pom.xml or the "name" property specified in build.sbt from within a java/scala class

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt

I have a library which is being added as a dependency in a maven and in a sbt project accordingly. How can I get the value of  and name from pom.xml and build.sbt respectively from a class residing within my jar e.g. myapp.jar.

I am able to access the application.conf or the application.properties from within myapp.jar but I want to directly access the build file. Is it possible?

Comment: Following is the pom.xml of application1:

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>application1</groupId>
 <artifactId>application1</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
      <dependency>
   <groupId>default</groupId>
   <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>

Comment: Following is the build.sbt of application2:

name := """application2"""
organization := "com.suvy"
version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

val dependencies = Seq(

"default" %% "myapp" % "1.0.0"
)